# Text before references, but after bibliography title with BibTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

How can I put some introductory text before the references in BibTeX, but after the bibliography title? I have found some reference to `\bibintro`, but it does not compile. I have tried with a fake reference, but it obviously has to start with many As ;)

Comment: Do you ask about a `bibtex` solution or one for `biblatex`? In your question you only mention the former, but you used the `biblatex` tag.

Answer (score 28):

Since you mentioned BibTeX in your question but tagged it with [biblatex](/questions/tagged/biblatex) I will provide solutions for both:

## Solution with BibTeX

Assuming you're using the `article` class you could redefine the `thebibliography` environment like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc {foo,
    author = {Foo, Francis},
    title = {All about Foo},
    year = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\myprenote}{Here goes my text.}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \myprenote
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Solution with `biblatex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {foo,
    author = {Foo, Francis},
    title = {All about Foo},
    year = {2011},
    location = {Footown},
}
@book {bar,
    author = {Bar, Bernie},
    title = {Barstory},
    year = {2000},
    location = {Barcity},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\defbibnote{myprenote}{Here goes my text.}
\printbibliography[prenote=myprenote]
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Thorsten!! Very useful. I just modified it slightly to uniform it with the book style. It was pretty hard to find a solution to this problem! (and sorry for wrong tagging..I meant bibtex in any case)

Comment: @UmbertoGrandi I'm glad that my answer helped you `:)` You can accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark (on the left side of my answer). When you register to this site and gain at least 15 reputation points you are also able to upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [natbib](https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib), you can simply define `\bibpreamble` for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@book {foo,
    author = {Foo, Francis},
    title = {All about Foo},
    year = {2011},
    location = {Footown},
}
@book {bar,
    author = {Bar, Bernie},
    title = {Barstory},
    year = {2000},
    location = {Barcity},
}
\end{filecontents}

\def\bibpreamble{Here goes my text.}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} 
\bibliography{example}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works very well! Great! What are the disadvantages of defining the command after \ begin{document}?

Comment: If that's admissible and it doesn't generate an error then I think it's fine