# Is there a way to manually add entries to the list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

I'm writing my thesis and one section is going to be made of an already existing article.

I'm including it with `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and`\includepdf[fitpaper=true, pages=-]{Impactpaper.pdf}`.

I'd like to add information about the figures contained in that paper to my list of figures (I have `\listoffigures` in the `frontmatter` of thesis).

```
% TableofContents
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

Is there a way to do add data in `\listoffigures` manually?

And also, is there a way to manually add data in the bibliography (citations)?

Comment: `\addcontentsline{lof}{<...>}` to add an entry with the page number or `\addtocontents{lof}{<...>}` to add an entry without the page number.

Comment: This may be relevant? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55030/text-before-references-but-after-bibliography-title-with-bibtex

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 5):

`addtolist` option is meant exactly for such a case.

Usage (copied from the official [**pdfpages** documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf)):

```
addtolist={<page number>, <type>, <headings>, <label>}
```

An example (copied from my thesis):

```
\includepdf[pages={-},
            addtolist={
                       3, figure, Schematic representation of the complete condition monitoring process., jps3:fig1,
                       4, table,  Archimedean copulas., jps3:tab1,
                       5, figure, Regions of best performance for different Archimedean copulas., jps3:fig2,
                       5, figure, Fully nested Archimedean copula., jps3:fig3,
                       5, figure, Nyquist plot of the PEM fuel cell impedance., jps3:fig4,
                       6, figure, Measurement sequences in time., jps3:fig5,
                       6, figure, Description of the regions for high and low copula outputs., jps3:fig6,
                       6, figure, Example of current and voltage signals during the experiment., jps3:fig7,
                       7, figure, Evolution of the health index (copula output)., jps3:fig8         
                      }
           ]{./journal_articles/jps2015.pdf}
```

An advice: if you have a comma in your heading, place it in curly brackets (e.g., This is a figure{,} which has a comma in its heading.).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I just reread the OPs question carefully, and see that he doesn't have TeX source for the figures he wants to document. So my solution is useless for him. I may leave it here for a while - perhaps someone will find it helpful.

This ugly hack works well enough for me, since I don't need the list of figures in the production version of my document.  Perhaps @PaulGessler 's solution in a comment above will work better for you. Perhaps I'll use it instead of mine ...

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}[2011/11/10]

\newcommand{\figcomment}[1]{%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\captionlistentry{comment: #1}
}

\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\captionlistentry{source: #1}
}
```

In the text:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=60mm]{\here/epalabel}
\caption{Gasoline Vehicle Label (2013)}
\figsource{Image download from 
\url{http://www.epa.gov/carlabel/gaslabel.htm}}
\figcomment{We should be able to use this government information
royalty free.}
\label{fig:epalabel}
\end{figure}
```

In the list of figures:

[image]

Comment: You are right, I do not have any tex files for my pdf file.